# Specify jQuery Auto-Complete Results Width

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

How would I specify the width of the results for the following jQuery Auto-Complete?

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,   
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
        response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
            return matcher.test( item );
        })
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Define CSS for `#autocomplete` in your stylesheet according to your requirement.

Comment: For some reason the JS over-rides doing something like this: #autocomplete { width: 200px !important; }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
 open: function() { 
                // After menu has been opened, set width to 100px
                $('.ui-menu')
                    .width(100);
            } ,
minLength: 2,   
source: function( request, response ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
return matcher.test( item );
}) );
}
```

Comment: does the open function you added go after the return matcher.test ( item ); statement?

Comment: Perfect thanks for the edit!  I'll accept this response when it allows me to.